# JSON Web Key (JWK) for IRS E services registration

Tags: jwk, irs

While signing up for the IRS E-services they are requesting a JSON Web Key (JWK). they want the following fields in the JWK
kid, kty, use, n, e, x5t, x5c.
The "kty" field should be equal to "RSA".

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70466021/7329832) it is shown how to generate the keys but I cannot find out how to generate an x5c key.

Answer (score 0):

x5c is fairly simple. you need to remove `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` from the `Self-Signed Certificate` generated from mkjwk.org

OR

you can use the PHP script: https://control7.net/JWK/generate.php

paste your `Public and Private Keypair` and `Self-Signed Certificate` into the textbox and click `Go`